# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'result'

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

while running the code

```
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
                 logging.info('shivaniHAHOHJSJKDNVJNCMBVJDCVHJSHHHHEKLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO')
        logging.info(data)
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            self.redirect('/error')
        json_post = response.read()
        data = json.loads(json_post)
        self.redirect('/'+str(data))
        response_dict = simplejson.loads(json_post)

        virustotal = VirusTotal()
        logging.info('1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111')
        logging.info('result')
        logging.info(data[int('result')])
        if data ['result'] == 0:
            virustotal_result = True
```

i get following in my log file

```
   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'result'
   INFO     2013-05-07 12:14:19,142 server.py:561] default: "GET /query?     url=abc.com&submit=Scan HTTP/1.1" 500 -
   INFO     2013-05-07 12:16:01,857 server.py:561] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1236
   INFO     2013-05-07 12:16:01,894 server.py:561] default: "GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
   INFO     2013-05-07 12:16:01,898 server.py:561] default: "GET /css/cssscript.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
   INFO     2013-05-07 12:16:01,943 server.py:561] default: "GET /images/left.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
   INFO     2013-05-07 12:16:01,950 server.py:561] default: "GET /images/right.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
   INFO     2013-05-07 12:16:01,950 server.py:561] default: "GET /images/bg.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
   INFO     2013-05-07 12:16:02,065 server.py:561] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 154
   WARNING  2013-05-07 12:16:10,082 urlfetch_stub.py:453] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
   INFO     2013-05-07 19:16:23,915 main.py:420] shivaniHAHOHJSJKDNVJNCMBVJDCVHJSHHHHEKLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
   INFO     2013-05-07 19:16:23,917 main.py:421] resource=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&scan=1&key=b99eeaddac6ef5cf62746beffd71f1e16708b6db6085de243f050e241c6c671f
   WARNING  2013-05-07 12:16:23,924 urlfetch_stub.py:453] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
   INFO     2013-05-07 19:16:33,023 main.py:432] 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
   INFO     2013-05-07 19:16:33,026 main.py:433] result
   ERROR    2013-05-07 19:16:33,028 webapp2.py:1528] invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'result'


     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shivani\Desktop\malbee-phish (1)\main.py", line 434, in get
    logging.info(data[int('result')])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'result'
```

what can be the possible reason..?? if i try data['result'] without int() it gives me following error
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 3):

Well of course this line won't work

`logging.info(data[int('result')])`  how is `int('result')` supposed to work?

Your stack trace is telling you exactly what the problem is.

So the question I ask you where are you getting a value for `result`

data['result'] could only work if data is a dictionary and you have a key in it with the value "result"

Alternately if data is a list (which is what the TypError list indices must be integers, not str is telling you, then result as a variable must be assigned an integer value at some point.  And no where in the code you just presented is result (a variable) ever assigned a value.

Comment: thanks for the input.. but plz do have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405750/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-sometimes-working-sometimes

Comment: That person has the same problem.  Look at what type `data` is.  This is pretty basic python.  Now have a look at the raw json.  My bet it is coming from some javascript and the round trip is not resulting in what you expect.  Do some basic debugging on what you have actually got from json loads.  Ultimately you can't get away from the fact you are trying to convert a non integer string to an int. - That just won't work, which is the error you asked about.

Comment: data is of list type .. and i m assigning the value to result in the beginning..  result = db.IntegerProperty().. i m really new to python and the value of result as printed is ..
INFO     2013-05-07 20:30:47,871 main.py:76] <google.appengine.ext.db.IntegerProperty object at 0x0000000004F6F080>
can u give me some syntactical guidelines to solve the same.. thanks

Comment: How are we supposed to work that out an assignment to result is not in the code you supplied.  And if you are assigning a value to result why are you using it as string literal.  Simplify the code to focus on the problem,your Original question is not the same as you are asking now.

Answer (score 2):

You have `int('result')` which will never work. Maybe you meant `int(result)`?

(Although I can't see how that would work either, seeing as you never assign to a variable `result`.)